# Text based installation for Server

Tags: server, text-mode

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 11.04 server on one of my machines (1U server) but graphics at the time of installation has an issue. Previously I would remove HDD connect it to other computer, install and put it back.

However I want a method to install on 1U server directly as it is being pain to do it so many times.

I read alternate CD is the only way, and alternate CD contains exactly same packages as Desktop CD. Now here is a problem I want Server packages and Text based installation.

If anyone know if there are particular boot options or some way to use alternate CD for Server packaged let me know.

BTW I've followed http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download (which says everything under link is Text based installer) but I don't think thats the case

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the link for Precice Pangolin on that page, then click on [ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64.iso](http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu-releases/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64.iso)  for the 64 bit server release, it will download what you need - A text based installer for the 64 bit server edition.

Don't forget to also get the [md5sums file](http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/releases/12.04.1/MD5SUMS) and check the iso after you have dowloaded and before you try to burn it.

Answer (score 0):

We use 11.04 server here.  Maybe try https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors
 for a mirror and then select either 32 or 64 bit under Server install CD from the mirror of your choice.

On a lot of servers it is the 3d graphics that mess you up and don't handle the mouse correctly. Sometimes I use a version 10 desktop and run from CD to format and partition drives etc.

Also note that some Dell (and probably other brand) servers may not have their drives seen by some versions of Ubuntu. The driver on the setup CD is not fully compatible with the dell raid drives and/or Grub has a hard time with them. In that case the alternate CD usually works or just try an older/newer version to get the install done.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks I'll try this one and yes issue here was I had to switch off ACPI